# Some PHP scripts running and others not running: Possible reasons?

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

Some of my PHP scripts (which are served by Apache) are running as expected, but others make Apache just return their source code. The PHP configuration doesn't seem to be the reasons as some of the scripts are running correctly.

Could anybody please explain possible reasons?

Comment: Make sure they have the correct ending, and have <?php at the begin

Comment: It would also help if you posted an example of what is not running.

Comment: there are few scripts in server. I am trying to execute a php (which is a api) script using postman its not executing the script it just returning the code of the script. But when some other applications which are using same server where the corresponding php scripts are running they are getting executed and running as expected. So few scripts are running as excpected where as few are not

Comment: @Alberto is the question too difficult to understand if thats the case i will try to rephrase it

Comment: Yes, please, thank you.

Comment: @Alberto  I have a bunch of scripts  in the apache2 server in the folder var/www/html when I try to execute few scripts they are not getting executed  where as few other scripts are executed. any specific reason why its happening that way.I have gone through error log and access log there is no trace of execution of the script. Any idea of such situation

Comment: @Alberto is this prashing proper

Comment: You eventually should show the source code of one of the scripts which does not run, as well as your Apache configuration. Furthermore, you might want to learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MuraliKrishnamraju If you only see the content of the files (the php code) when requesting them using Postman, it means that either you don't have php installed or properly configured on your server, or the php file doesn't contain the <?php tag at the very beginning of the file.

Comment: Hey I am new to this forum if I am not clear excuse me for this and  i need to learn asking questions better

Comment: hey thanks for the help guys issue got solved problem is script is not starting with <?php. I am new to php and i am directly dealing with existing code. Thanks for the help

Comment: Like first comment said hehe

Comment: @DieterKräutl yeah btw thanks